# Azure VM Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, virtual-machine

I just got finished creating a VM in Azure and called it vm123. I was trying to use that VM when creating my SQL Server.
When I create a SQL Database in Azure, it forces me to either create a server or pick one from dropdown.
Why can't I see my vm123 in the list?

[image: PICTURE: Do not see vm123 on the list]

I can create a new one alright, which is what I did, since my VM did not appear in the dropdown. How do I remote into it?
See screenshots...
[image: PICTURE: I created new server while creating database but can't remote into it]

Comment: Because a VM and a SQL Server (as a Service) are two different resources. You have to create a SQL Server Server (as a Service), which is normally hosted on .database.windows.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing VM with the Database server, the one asked in the dropdown is a SQL server not a VM. Those two are two different services on Azure.

To fix this create a SQL server resource first and you should be able to see that in the dropdown when you create the database.

Comment: so it is a sql server instance name, i guess....?  (in the non cloud world)

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database is a managed service and the underlying infrastructure is shared across tenants.

If you really need access to the host then you'll need to choose from one of the following:

1. Create a SQL Server VM (includes licensing but at a higher operational cost)
2. Create a Windows Server VM and install a SQL instance on it.  You must license it yourself accordingly.